# Eigen: initialize matrix with N identical rows

Tags: matrix, vector, initialization, row, eigen

I would like to initialize a matrix in Eigen (Eigen::MatrixXf) that consists of N identical row vectors, how could I do that? I tried to search for that in documentation, but couldn't find any constructor, that would apply in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Eigen::RowVectorXf row; // the row you want to replicate

Eigen::MatrixXf Mat(row.colwise().replicate(N));
```

`replicate` is documented [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a4f89ab26ccf66c3a9d0190e10243cb9e) and [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1VectorwiseOp.html#abbfe4630c6d1209351a7d142182713af).